# TypeError while accessing the parent function using dunder proto in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, prototype, proto

Below is my sample code,

```
function Employee(name){
  this.name = name;
}

Employee.prototype.getName = function(){
  return this.name;
}

var a = new Employee("a");

function Manager(name){
  this.name = name;
}

var b = new Manager("b");

//Case:1

Manager.__proto__ = Employee.prototype;
console.log(b.getName());

//Case:2
b.__proto__.__proto__ = Employee.prototype;
console.log(b.getName());
```

*Case: 1* When the Manager's dunder proto is pointing to the Employee prototype it produces TypeError(**TypeError: b.getName is not a function**).

*Case: 2* However in this case when the Employee prototype is pointed starting from the Manager's instance dunder proto(i.e. `b.__proto__`), this would work fine and gives the correct result.

According to the law of inheritance, 
**1.** instance 'b' initially looks for the function `getName` in itself if it was created through the constructor mode.
**2.** Else would look for the `getName` in Manager's prototype object.
**3.** Now the next level is `Object.prototype`.

Please correct me if I am wrong in any sense.

But I would wish to point the Manager's `__proto__` to Employee prototype instead of `Object.prototype`.
I tried to achieve this by `Manager.__proto__ = Employee.prototype;` and `b.__proto__.__proto__ = Employee.prototype;`. Only the latter worked correctly.

Why did `Manager.__proto__ = Employee.prototype;` throw `TypeError` when both the methods are pointing to Employee prototype??

Comment: What is "dunder"?

Comment: `b.__proto__ === Manager.prototype !== Manager`

Comment: Agreed. So the only way to access any Object's prototype is through an istance(`b.__proto__.__proto__`) is it?? Because `Manager.prototype.__proto__` is not a valid operation.

Comment: `b.__proto__.__proto__` is exactly the same  as `Manager.prototype.__proto__` - not sure what you mean by "not a valid operation"? The only invalid thing here is the use of the deprecated `__proto__` property.